# How do I query to find if values in one table have any corresponding entries in other tables

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to write a query that will check to see if values in one table have any corresponding entries in other tables.   I have the following which works but is there a faster way?  Maybe using exists() function?

For clarification, this will be in sqlite.  Also, I need values for each row in Manufacturer and whether or not it has entries in any of the other tables.

```
select tM.val, min(t1.val) as MakesCars, min(t2.val)  as MakesTrucks,
 min(t3.val) as MakesVans  from tableManufactures tM 
left join tableCars t1 on tM.id = t1.Manid
left join tableTrucks t2 on tM.id = t2.Manid
left join tableVans t3 on tM.id = t3.Manid
group by tM.val
order by tM.val
```

Results would look something like this:

```
Manufacturer  MakesCars  MakesTrucks  MakesVans
Ford          85         15           20
Chevy         72         12           NULL
Mazda         42         NULL         NULL
```

So any value would indicate that they do make that and a null would indicate that they don't.

Comment: what RDBMS is this ??

Comment: Do you need the values that are only present in all three tables and tableManufactures, or those that are present in tableManufactures and any one of the three tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the joins, the database has to look up all matching records, most of which are then dropped because of the min().

Using EXISTS indeed is likely to be more efficient:

```
SELECT val,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM tableCars
               WHERE Manid = tM.id) AS MakesCars,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM tableTrucks
               WHERE Manid = tM.id) AS MakesTrucks,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM tableVans
               WHERE Manid = tM.id) AS MakesVans
FROM tableManufactures AS tM
ORDER BY val
```